# Minimising a complex modulus

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $u, v$ and $w$ are complex numbers such that $|u|=5$, $|v| = 7$ and $|w| = 19$. What is the smallest value that $|u+v+w|$ can attain?

I used the inequality $|u+v+w| \ge |u| - |v| - |w|$ to attain the value $-21$ however how do I know this is the minimum possible value for the total modulus and how would I justify this?

Comment: We always have $\lvert u + v + w\rvert \geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequalities
$$
 |u+v+w| \ge |u| - |v| - |w| = 5 - 7 - 19 = -21 \\
 |u+v+w| \ge |v| - |u| - |w| = 7 - 5 - 19 = -17
$$
are both true. So $-21$ and $-17$ are both *lower bounds* for
$|u+v+w|$, but that does not give anything useful because
$|u+v+w| \ge 0$ holds in general. So these lower bounds cannot
be the *minimum* (the value is not attained).

You need to utilize the fact that $|w|$ is larger than $|u| + |v|$
and put $w$ in front:
$$
|u+v+w| = |w+(u+v)| \ge |w| - |u + v|  \ge |w| - (|u| + |v|)
= |w| - |u| - |v| = 19 - 5 - 7 = 7
$$
Now we have a *non-negative* estimate for $|u+v+w|$.
That value is attained for $u = -5, v = -7, w = 19$, so it is indeed
the minimum value.

Comment: Would you care to justify this ?

Comment: @MichaelHowlard: Which part is unclear? I used the same triangle inequality as you did in the question, I only applied it to the variables in a different ordering.

Comment: How did you know what ordering to use?

Comment: @MichaelHowlard: As I added to the question: $|w| = 21$ is "dominant" in the sense that it is larger than $|u| + |v| = 12$.

Comment: Oh sorry! Ok - so I why not use the version I did in my question, as it provides a smaller minimum?

Comment: Also it seems you have made a mistake in your working. We have that $|u+v| \ge |u| - |v|$ therefore $$|w| - |u+v| \ge |w| - |u| + |v|$$

Comment: @MichaelHowlard: You have shown that $-21$ is a *lower bound", but it cannot be the minimum (because it is negative). I have edited my answer to explain that better. – And no, there is no error in the inequalities, I have extended that part as well to make it clear.

Comment: Ok - that answers all my questions, thanks for your time.